# Snowflake | How to parse a json array to get a key's values as a list using SQL

Tags: sql, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Here is a sample row of my json array column called location in my table.

```
[
  {
    "row": "8",
    "seat": "30",
    "section": "WJ"
  },
  {
    "row": "8",
    "seat": "32",
    "section": "WJ"
  },
  {
    "row": "8",
    "seat": "34",
    "section": "WJ"
  }
]
```

I want to extract "section", "row" and a list of all the "seats", such that the section, row, and seat columns in my table for this row look as follows:

```
+---------+-----+----------+
| section | row | seats    |
|---------+-----+----------+
|   WJ    |  8  | 30,32,34 |
```

I first exploded my table to the section and row level using lateral flatten in the from clause, then I used listagg to aggregate the seats into a list. This process is inefficient and extremely slow as I have over a million records. What is a more efficient way of doing this?

```
select
        flatten_json.value:section::string as listing_section,
        flatten_json.value:row::string as listing_row,
        listagg(distinct flatten_json.value:seat::string, ',') within group (order by try_to_number(flatten_json.value:seat::string)) as listing_seat
from table,
lateral flatten(input => parse_json(location), outer => true) as flatten_json
group by
        flatten_json.value:section,
        flatten_json.value:row
```

Comment: Hi - if you want to speed it up you'd need to write the flattened data out to a table and then query that table and/or (possibly) try running your query with a larger warehouse

Comment: Can you define what you mean with "inefficient" and "extremely slow"? I would expect Snowflake to execute this code quickly if it's only a million rows.